# Slash command not showing (discord.py Client)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a simple slash command. However, when I run the code, the command is not being shown in discord.

```
import os
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")
GUILD = os.getenv("GUILD_ID")

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
slash = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Finding guild...")
    guild = None
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    print("Initializing command tree...")
    await slash.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guild.id))
    print(f'{client.user} is connected to guild {guild.name} (id: {guild.id})')

@client.event
async def close():
    print(f"{client.user} disconnected.")

@slash.command(name="ticket", description="new ticket")
async def create_ticket(message, tag: str, title: str, content: str, level: str):
    print(message, "\n", tag, title, content, level)
```

I tried looking for solution on the internet, but all of them were for `discord.Bot`, not `discord.Client`.
I learned about `slash commands` just today, sorry if it is an easy mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every time you create a slash command, you must reboot discord for it to update. On another note, even though you fixed it, it is much better to use pycord for slash commands, views, and many more things. Pycord is a fork of discord.py, so it can do everything discord.py can, too!

Here is how to create a slash command with pycord:

```py
import discord

bot = discord.Bot()
          
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I CONNECTED TO DISCORD!")

@bot.slash_command(name="name_of_slash_command", description="description_of_slash_command")
@option(name="option_1 (string)", type=str, description="description for option 1")
@option(name="option_2 (integer)", type=int, description="description for option 2")
#Option types are not restricted to str and int. They can potentially be anything, provided that the user passes in valid data.
async def name_of_slash_command(ctx, option_1, option_2):
    await ctx.respond("Response to slash command!")
```

Comment: This code is using `discord.Bot`. I said that I am using `discord.Client`.

Comment: Why do you need to use discord.Client?

Comment: I already wrote the entirety of code with ```discord.Client```. Simply because that is what I am working with at all times. My bot mainly uses ```on_message```, so I don't see any reason to change it.

Comment: If you use on_message, then you cannot use slash commands. You will need to convert all your code anyway.

Comment: I mean, it still works, I don't see much reason to change it.

Comment: Okay, but I was just saying that going forward Pycord will be much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there is no problem with the code itself. It is just **Discord**, the `command` showed up after I rebooted **Discord**...
*No clue why, but I am glad it works. Sorry.*